System.AccessViolationException in AviFile manager when creating a video from bitmap images
I am working on add-in for Solidworks. In this add-in, an AviFile.dll library is used to create a video from bitmap images. While creating a video stream object, a System.AccessViolation exception is thrown.
This is my code:
string videosFilePath = _flowPlusPath + "\\videos";
Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePaths[0]);

string[] directories = _flowPlusPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string prefix = directories [directories.Length-2]+" ("+ directories[directories.Length - 1]+") " + "-";

int index = SolverHelper.GetStartFileIndex(videosFilePath, prefix) + 1;
string videoName = Path.Combine(videosFilePath, prefix + index.ToString("000") + ".avi");

AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(videoName, false); ;
Avi.AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS opts = SetCompressOptions();

try
{
    VideoStream aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(true, 5, bitmap1); // Here exception is thrown
    PopulateVideoStream(aviStream, imageFilePaths);
}

I checked the bitmap1 parameter passed to this. It is not null. Also note that the same code is used in another standalone application for video making but there is no issue observed.
Earlier we had Solidworks 2021 version and there was no exception issue. This is observed when we upgraded to Solidworks 2023 version.
Please suggest the possible reasons for this issue.
